# Validate EditText input and update user score

Tags: java, android-studio

Case:
I am asking user a question to which the answer is `7`.

How do I validate that entry of `EditText` is 7 and after which I want to award 1 point to their score.

```
//Question #1  
//If Answer is equal to 7 than award One Point   
int = score;

private EditText questionOneAnswer;

EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Part2Question1);

String EditText = text.getText().toString().trim();

if(EditText.isEmpty() || EditText.length() == 0 || 
  EditText.equals("7") || EditText == null)
   {
    //EditText is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you can't use predefined class names as variable names. Second is that you logic for awarding point is incorrect. Try this,

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Part2Question1);
String answer = text.getText().trim();

if(answer.equals("7"))
   {
    score++;
   }
else{
     // show some toast showing that answer is incorrect
   }
```